# Create variable in PHP regardless if value is set

Tags: php

If I were to create this variable:

```
$example = $_GET['test'];
```

I would get this error message if `$_GET['test']` is not set:

```
Notice: Undefined variable...
```

How can I create variables like this (without having to use `if` statements and the like) without having to see this error message?

Comment: Just turn off notices in php.

Comment: I want to see error messages while I'm still coding, though, just not these.

Comment: McKracken is surely being sarcastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$example = isset($_GET['test']) ? $_GET['test'] : NULL;
```

Comment: I would upvote you, but that second example makes me want to do the opposite.

Comment: Just like I said - I don't prefer to use `@` either. And I even don't want to teach somebody to do so, but it's just an example what is possible.

Comment: This is a bad practice. There is absolutly no reason to use it as long as you have good one.

Comment: Don't even mention it then!  Folks come on this site and copy and paste stuff without paying attention, creating a real mess.

Comment: Ok, I agree. Someone might follow a bad practice because they saw it on stackowerflow. Removed.

Comment: So I have to set the variable based on whether or not the value is set and then I have to read the variable's value again later to see if it is set. Coding PHP without the error messages on is a lot easier. Thanks for this, though.

Comment: @UserIsCorrupt It's only easier until you actually get an error :/

Comment: This is not just a matter of getting rid of an error - you could have a default value of anything you want and this default value might be `NULL` - why not? Consider this example: `$n = isset($_GET['n']) ? (int)$_GET['n'] : 10;` - now this is really something useful. here you both providing the default value and sanitizing users input. You might have a function that outputs last 10 lines of the file with [`tail`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)): `function get_last_lines($fname,$n=10) { echo \`tail -n $n $fname\`; }`. Now you're protected from this attack: `?n=10;%20cat%20/etc/passwd`

Comment: @Nemoden, Don't rely on typecasting to make args safe for running other commands.  What if you needed to use a string value?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I do something like the following:

```
function get($key, $default = null) {
   return isset($_GET[$key]) ? trim($_GET[$key]) : $default;
}

$example = get('test');
```